# Fabric js. Unable to select object at specific location in canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am unable to select object only at this specific location (area) in the canvas. At all other locations of the canvas I am able to successfully select object.

[image]

My code: -

```
const initCanvas = () =>
    new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current, {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      width: window.innerWidth * 0.6,
      height: window.innerHeight * 0.68,
      controlsAboveOverlay: true,
      fireRightClick: true, 
      fireMiddleClick: true,
      stopContextMenu: true,
      preserveObjectStacking: true,
    });


  useEffect(() => {
    fabricCanvasRef.current = initCanvas();

    fabric.Object.prototype.set({
      transparentCorners: false,
      cornerColor: "rgba(0,0,100,0.8)",
      cornerSize: 15,
      cornerStyle: "circle",
      padding: 0,
      lockScalingFlip: true,
      preserveObjectStacking: true,
      dirty: false
      // objectCaching: false,
    });

    fabricCanvasRef.current.on("mouse:down", (obj) => {
      /** It is 1 when its left click */
      if (obj.button === 1) {
        setIsRightClickMenuVisible(false);
      } else if (obj.button === 3) {
        // its 3 when right click
        if (obj !== null && obj !== undefined && obj.target !== null) {
          setCurrentActiveObject(obj.target);

          setRightClickX(obj.pointer.x);
          setRightClickY(obj.pointer.y);
          setIsRightClickMenuVisible(true);
        }
      }
      fabricCanvasRef.current.renderAll();
    });

    // destroy fabric on unmount
    return () => {
      fabricCanvasRef.current.dispose();
      fabricCanvasRef.current = null;
    };
  }, []);
```

So, I cant understand that - for all objects which are outside that red area - I am able to click / modify them - but its only near that red area - object selection is not happening. I am unable to click corners for resizing / rotating near that red area. At all other different locations of the canvas it is working fine. Kindly help.